# __timeShift function not returning the previous year date

Tags: datetime, time, jmeter, timeshift

I'm using the __timeShift function as follows

```
${__timeShift(YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm,,-P7D,,)}
```

My **current date is 3rd of January 2023.**
I'm **expecting 2022-12-27 02:13** but **getting output as 2023-12-27 02:13**.

If my current date is 10th of January 2023, then I should get output as 2023-01-03 02:13.
So I should be able to get the date 7 days previous to current date.

I'm not sure how to give the formatting and options in __timeShift function to have proper date. Please do help me in this.

[Here is what I have tried... Link to Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOXQv.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
${__timeShift(YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm,,-7D,,)}
```

This will shift the current date backwards by 7 days, and the output will be in the format YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm, as specified by the first parameter.

If you want to include the time in the output, you can specify the current time using the __time function, like this:

```
${__timeShift(YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm,${__time(hh:mm)},-7D,,)}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue using latest stable [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5) and the following [__timeShift()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__timeShift) function syntax:

```
${__timeShift(YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm,,-P7D,,)}
```

[image]

so double check your operating system date and ensure you're using the latest stable JMeter version which is available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page.

Comment: I have latest stable JMeter 5.5.  But still facing this issue. And system date is having current date and is proper. Anything in specific I have to check and update in the system DateTime settings?